# How to query from the table using group by with EF6?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have the table below and I need a query which groups the roleId values into a list and put it into the DTO. Example and expected result are below the table.

I know it should not be complex stuff but I can't figure out how... I went through a few examples and I have found only examples where they deal with the count of grouped stuff and not the list of them.

```
+----+--------+--------+
| id | userId | roleId |
+----+--------+--------+
|  1 | 1      |    1   |
+----+--------+--------+
|  2 | 1      |    2   |
+----+--------+--------+
| 3  |  2     |    1   |
+----+--------+--------+
```

```
public class UserRoleDto
    {
        public int userId { get; set; }

        public List<int> roleIds { get; set; }
    }
```

Expected result:

```
var res = new List<UserRoleDto>
            {
                new UserRoleDto()
                {
                    userId = 1,
                    roleIds = new List<int>() {1, 2}
                },
                new UserRoleDto()
                {
                    userId = 2,
                    roleIds = new List<int>() {1}
                }
            };
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Supposing you have mapped the junction table as an entity on your model, you could do this:

```
using(var db=new YourContext())
{
    var res= db.UserRoles.GroupBy(ur=>ur.userId)
                         .Select(g=>new UserRoleDto()
                                    { 
                                      userId = g.Key,
                                      roleIds = g.Select(us=>us.roleId).ToList()
                                    } 
                                ).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you very much! The roleIds part in the select was missing.